# Sequencing Async Call in For Loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem with a asynchronous call in a for loop. The loop continues before the async call finishes. I'm pretty new to this language and trying to grasp callbacks ..etc. I have tried a self calling function, promise and timeout but still can't get the flow to work as intended.

I want the call to firebase to complete before the profile object gets pushed into the messages array.

```
// returns the chats for that profile
Chat.allChatsByUser(uid).$loaded()
 .then(function(data) {     
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   // self calling function for async callback handling
   // this ensures that the async call is run for every iteration in the loop
   (function(i) {
      var item = data[i];
      // function to arrange users and chats fom newest to oldest
      // for each matched user. item.$id = uid              
      Auth.getProfile(item.$id).$loaded()
      .then(function(profile) { 
         // first function handles success
         if (typeof profile === 'object') { 
              if(chat.keyOrder == 'true') {

              // get last chat from firebase
              // WANT THIS COMPLETE BEFORE CONTINUING                       
              ref.child('chatting').child('messages').child(chat.chatId).on("value", function(data) {
                 profile.lastChat = data.child('lastMsg').val();
              });

             // pushes chatting users profile into the array
             chat.messages.push(profile);    

         } else {
               // invalid response
               return $q.reject(profile);
         }
 }, function(profile) {
   // promise rejected
   console.log('error', error);});
 // i argument as closure
 })(i);
}
```

Appreciate any assistance or guidance.

Thanks,
Noel

Comment: Have you tried including `chat.messages.push(profile);` within `value`  event handler?

Comment: Spot on. That fixed it. Thanks for taking time to look and respond :-) So simple but been banging my head for hours!

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you want two separate things actually, one, you want your loop to not continue until after the async call is complete. Im pretty sure there are fancy ways to do this with es6 but you aren't using es6. I'm not sure why you want the loop to wait though? So I've improvised by using a while loop. Second you want "want the call to firebase to complete before the profile object gets pushed into the messages array." This is done by putting the push call within the `value` event handler as mentioned in the first comment.

```
// returns the chats for that profile
Chat.allChatsByUser(uid).$loaded()
    .then(function(data) {
            var i = 0;
            var inProgress = false;
            while (i < data.length) {
                // self calling function for async callback handling
                // this ensures that the async call is run for every iteration in the loop

                // wait until last iteration has completed
                while(inProgress);

                // the function is about to begin
                inProgess = true;
                (function(i) {
                        // increment i here
                        var item = data[i++];
                        // function to arrange users and chats fom newest to oldest
                        // for each matched user. item.$id = uid              
                        Auth.getProfile(item.$id).$loaded()
                            .then(function(profile) {
                                    // first function handles success
                                    if (typeof profile === 'object') {
                                        if (chat.keyOrder == 'true') {

                                            // get last chat from firebase
                                            // WANT THIS COMPLETE BEFORE CONTINUING                       
                                            ref.child('chatting').child('messages').child(chat.chatId).on("value", function(data) {
                                                profile.lastChat = data.child('lastMsg').val();

                                                // wait until event
                                                // pushes chatting users profile into the array
                                                chat.messages.push(profile);

                                                // allow next iteration to continue
                                                inProgess = false;
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            // invalid response
                                            return $q.reject(profile);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    function(profile) {
                                        // promise rejected END script
                                        return console.log('error', error);
                                    });
                                // i argument as closure
                            })(i);
                }
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for responding mate. I'll take this format on when performing similar data flow. Been trying to get used to async programming as come from sequential coding background. Putting it in value event handler did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, please consider choosing an answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Include `chat.messages.push(profile)` within `value` handler

```
ref.child('chatting').child('messages').child(chat.chatId)
.on("value", function(data) {
  profile.lastChat = data.child('lastMsg').val();
  // pushes chatting users profile into the array
  chat.messages.push(profile);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the .all method is the way to go with something like this.  For example:

```
function loadMeetings(city,state) {

    return ref.child('states').child(state).child(city).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var reads = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var id = childSnapshot.key();
        var promise = ref.child('meetings').child(id).once('value').then(function(snap) {
            return snap.val();
        }, function(error) {
            // The Promise was rejected.
            console.error(error);
        });
        reads.push(promise);
    });
    return Promise.all(reads);
    }, function(error) {
        // The Promise was rejected.
        console.error(error);
    }).then(function(values) {
        //for each snapshot do something
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Push to the array within the value event handler:

```
ref.child('chatting').child('messages').child(chat.chatId)
 .on("value", function(data) {
    profile.lastChat = data.child('lastMsg').val();

    // pushes chatting users profile into the array
    chat.messages.push(profile); 
});
```